# Host not HVM enabled?

Tags: apache-cloudstack

When I try to deploy an instance with my template onto a LXC hypervisor host,I get the error message:

```
2013-11-10 20:30:11,319 DEBUG [allocator.impl.FirstFitAllocator]
(Job-Executor-5:job-19 = [ d070b5ba-f342-4252-9137-4d2c1b19eca6 ]
FirstFitRoutingAllocator) Not considering hosts: [Host[-4-Routing]]
to deploy template:
Tmpl[201-TAR-201-2-7444dd2e-2fe3-347b-a9cc-97ba7bdca211 as they are
not HVM enabled
```

what does that mean?Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: A workaround for XenServer hypervisors is here: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132015

Answer (score 1):

HVM is a hardware virtualization technology. Some of its extended features require a compatible processor, motherboard, and BIOS, but you may be able to get it working with just a compatible processor **and enabling hardware virtualization in your BIOS setup.**

CloudStack, according to its docs, requires HVM as a minimum requirement. (I don't know why - HVM is certainly not needed for LXC!)

I bought a new desktop PC motherboard specifically to get HVM with extended features on my PC - after two failed attempts! So if you post a question on SuperUser or ServerFault about buying hardware (probably ServerFault would be the most appropriate site for this), I can try to help you with that followup question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to fool cloudstack into believing that the hypervisor is "HVM" enabled. This does not affect anything, and things work as expected. It seems to be a design flaw in Cloudstack.

Comment: how exactly this can be achieve? your answer is not given enough information to the question submitter